# Backport prototype setProperty checks to 6.x

Tags: protobuf.js

Could you please have a look into https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/pull/1910 and help many people to ensure security of their apps without major (to 7.x) upgrade? Thanks in advance!

There are few people tagging maintainers in repo, though there is no much reaction